# MVC .NET App that accesses files in mobile device

Tags: css, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, html

I want to build a "mobile first" ASP.NET MVC (ecommerce) Website, and I need it to be as "Internet" light as possible on the company agents' cellphones since they may have limited Internet in the field.

Is there a way to create a .NET Website, and have it check for local files when it's run through a mobile device?? The kind of files would pretty much be anything that's static for the site (CSS, JS, Images, some htmls...) so they get loaded from the phone's SD card instead of downloading from web.

The website will be mostly used by field agents that need to ask for equipment when with a customer, so any required configurations can be made to their phone beforehand.

Also, this website should be able to work normally when using it from a PC. So it should be able to work with Local files and normal Server files 
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076800/can-a-website-html5-javascript-access-a-mobile-devices-android-iphone-conta

Comment: Yeah, not the answer I was hoping for, but makes sense. I wonder though if I could create all of those files as localstorage when the website is first executed from the Phone so it can access those files when they are available. Kind of like a never expiring big fast cache.

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache but note what it says about deprecation. If this is an internal audience then look towards Service Workers

Comment: appCache != localstorage...Just sayin' -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986026/is-appcache-application-cache-web-storages-localstorage

Comment: appCache seems like pretty much what I need. Too bad it's getting deprecated. I'll look into Service Workers.
And the other option I'm thinking of is using static htmls and JS as UI stored in the Phone and make Ajax calls for authentication and DB interaction. But that seems like a lot of pointless effort...